# FROM keyword not found

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am getting an error, even though I actually do have the keyword!

Here's my code:

```
SELECT TOP(10) * FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Here's the error:

> [42000][923] ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think it is not correct syntax for Oracle in terms of TOP N

Comment: use ROWNUM instead of using TOP N

Comment: Correct the syntax. Insert the keyword FROM where appropriate. The SELECT list itself also may be in error. If quotation marks were used in an alias, check that double quotation marks enclose the alias. Also, check to see if a reserved word was used as an alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the right way of accessing top # rows

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE ROWNUM <= 10
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should not use `top` or `limit` or anything like that unless you are using `order by`.  In Oracle, the traditional way to write your query is:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY <something goes here>
WHERE rownum <= 10;
```

You can omit the `ORDER BY`, but then you will get an arbitrary set of 10 rows that might change from one call to another.